# What is the default sharing permission for NETLOGON and SYSVOL?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, microsoft

I have a Windows Server 2012 AD server.

Some time ago I changed the default sharing permissions for NETLOGON and SYSVOL.

Now some users are complaining that the notification that the password is about to expire is no longer showing, but the policy is configured correctly.

I suspect it is due to the changes I made to NETLOGON and SYSVOL so I would like to check what the default sharing permission is for NETLOGON and SYSVOL?

How can I leave these options in the safest way that does not affect the execution of the scripts?

Thank you

Comment: `the policy is configured correctly` is the policy applying correctly?

Comment: you can always spin up a single VM and install a separate domain on it, to verify (new) defaults in Active Directory

Answer (score 1):

NETLOGON and SYSVOL require either Everyone or Authenticated Users security principals with both Read and Execute permissions.

Everyone or Authenticated Users are identical for the purposes of assigning permissions.

Authenticated Users includes Domain Computers, to enable reading of policies.